# rsync only folder without files inside and without scanning files

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I would like to use rsync to sync only folder between folder a and b

```
> rsync -zaSH --delete -vv --delete -f"+ f/" -f"- f/*" a/ b
sending incremental file list
[sender] showing directory f because of pattern f/
[sender] hiding file f/1.data because of pattern f/*
[sender] hiding file f/4.data because of pattern f/*
[sender] hiding file f/8.data because of pattern f/*
[sender] hiding file f/10.data because of pattern f/*
[sender] hiding file f/6.data because of pattern f/*
[sender] hiding file f/3.data because of pattern f/*
[sender] hiding file f/5.data because of pattern f/*
[sender] hiding file f/9.data because of pattern f/*
[sender] hiding file f/7.data because of pattern f/*
[sender] hiding file f/2.data because of pattern f/*
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
f/
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 88 bytes  received 90 bytes  356.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

> tree 
.
├── a
│   └── f
│       ├── 10.data
│       ├── 1.data
│       ├── 2.data
│       ├── 3.data
│       ├── 4.data
│       ├── 5.data
│       ├── 6.data
│       ├── 7.data
│       ├── 8.data
│       └── 9.data
└── b
    └── f
```

As can be seen from the verbose output, the files were still scanned. If there are millions of files in the folder that could take very long. 
Is there a way to achieve the same goal without scanning files? Thanks.

Comment: rsync has to scan the directory f in case it has another subdirectory f. directory entries are not sorted; going through entries and testing for a match is always costly.

Comment: @meuh, Thanks. What if I don't care f's subdirectories. Is there a way to avoid the scan?

Comment: I dont think so. You could try using `find` to create a list of files/directories to copy, then pass that to rsync `--files-from`. Using find's `-prune` option might allow it to skip the rest of a directory; it depends how it is implemented. Or if you know the exact list of names you can put them in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop it scanning the files directly inside `a/f/`, but it shouldn't scan any subdirectories of those unless they are also called `f`.

This command will exclude those too:

```
rsync -aSH --delete -vv --delete -f"+ /f/" -f"- /f/*" a/ b/
```

Prefixing patterns with `/` means match the root of the source directory.

(I also removed `-z` because compression makes no sense for local copies.)

Comment: Thanks. I've used two rsyncs to avoid the scan: **1**. `rsync -aSH --delete -vv --delete -f"- /f/" a/ b/` to exclude the folder f. **2**.  Use rsync `--files-from` to sync only folder.

Comment: use `--chmod=ugo=rwX` option if you are in remote. for later study